# How to install rosserial into catkin_ws in ROS Groovy...?

Tags: ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to connect ROS with my Arduino , But this requires rosserial_arduino to be installed inside the working directory. I tired but the procedure looks complicated and different from fuerte .........

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51440/how-to-install-rosserial-into-catkin_ws-in-ros-groovy...?/) by [Cybertron](https://answers.ros.org/users/3895/cybertron/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-01-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not sure, but this package does not look like it was catkinized, so you will have to build it in a rosbuild environment. Check the catkin tutorial: using_rosbuild_with_catkin for more information

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0